# Have either of the Icewind Dale video games been published as d20-compatible adventures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms

My own searches did not yield any results on adaptations of the [*Icewind Dale* video game series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icewind_Dale_(series))' story into pen & paper adventures. All I could find were adaptions for other video games like Neverwinter Nights.

So, have their plots ever been converted into a published campaign, adventure modules, or adventure path that is compatible with D&D 3.x or Pathfinder? I don't think there is anything official, but maybe there is something fan-based?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Considering *Icewind Dale* is set in the Forgotten Realms, any published adventure is going to be for some edition of D&D, no? Shouldn’t this question therefore have that tag? I could see it helping search results in the future, maybe.

Comment: @KRyan That's a good point, at least for official adventures. I'm a bit torn on the tagging though: normally tags shouldn't be used to indicate what we guess the answer might turn out to be, only for what the question is about. If (possibly fan-made) adaptations for only D&D/PF are acceptable though, then I think the tag(s) would make sense? What do you think? (Now that it's mentioned though, this definitely merits the FR tag.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Hm, agreed that it’s contentious to guess what the answer might be. But it doesn’t sound like an adaptation to Fate or whatever would help much, which implies it is a constraint on the question, too. For that matter, considering the differences between editions of D&D, a 2e or 4e adaptation might not help much either. Most of the material you’d get from that could just as easily come from the game itself; the actual conversion to fit a system work would have to be redone.

Comment: @KRyan Yeah, and it was at first phrased that widely for D&D editions. Hey Patta, are *only* answers for Pathfinder or D&D 3.x useful? Is that an essential part of the question, or is any adaptation at all what you are looking for?

Comment: I was primarily thinking about PF and 3.5, Yes, as those are the rules i am familiar with, but i originally decided to include other versions of DnD because I felt results would be more likely.

Comment: Also curious about this. I had been making my own reconstruction of the adventure into a d20 format. I haven't found any official reproductions of it either.

Comment: How far did you make it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a fairly comprehensive collection of the official modules and can confirm there were no official adaptations (or any released as web exclusive content).  I have never seen a fan module either, though there are a number of threads with people who started to do so in various editions or are running their own variation (a couple examples below).

It might be worth following up on those message boards to see if the participants have content they're willing to share.  At a minimum, the threads frequently have official sources of data on the Icewind Dales region at least.

http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?276923-FR-Icewind-Dale
http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?196640-Icewind-Dale-Campaign